# How does Serverfault accept your Yahoo/Google credentials?

Tags: discussion, security

What is the technical mechanism for this feature exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called [Open ID](http://openid.net/) and has been around for some time. It's a method where authentication sources can securely share authenticated/not-authenticated data with relying parties. Sites like StackExchange use this so they don't have to run authentication services themselves, and can let the bigger parties handle that.

Google and Yahoo both support Open ID.

Comment: 'so they don't have to run authentication services themselves' ... of course we are also an OpenID provider now ... :)

Comment: @Zypher Yeah but that's new. When y'all were a scrappy startup, you didn't have one.

Comment: After using my Yahoo to login to unix.stackexchange for the first time, I am getting a lot of email sent/spoofed from my yahoo address.